# Using a file, write 60 random grades, with values between 50 and 100 into a file. Read the file, count and display the number as grades A - f

Tags: java

I have already figured out getting the 60 random integers for the grades between 50 - 100 but I am having trouble with using those numbers and making them display whether the numbers have a grade of A - F. Also the numbers determining these grades are A = 90 - 100, B = 80 - 89, C = 70 - 79, D = 60 -69, and F = 50 - 59.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String filename;
    String aNum;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Name of the file
    System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
    filename = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    //Opens the file
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);
    
    //Hopefully gets data from the method and writes it    
    for(int i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
    {
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        int min = 50;
        int max = 100;
        
        int x = randomNumbers.nextInt(max - min) + min;
        System.out.print("The grades are : " + x);
        aNum = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.println(aNum);
    }
    
   //Closes file
    outputFile.close();
    System.out.println("Grades have been written to the file.");
   
  int number = 0;
  int grade = 0;
   
   //making sure file exists
   File file = new File(filename);
   if (!file.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("The file " + filename + "is not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
   
   //opens file and reads
   Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
   
    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
    //Read values from file adn reads it
    number = inputFile.nextInt();
    

    if(grade < 60)
    {
        System.out.println("You recieved an F. ");
    }
    else if(grade < 70)
            {
              System.out.println("You recieved a D. ");
            }
    else if(grade < 80)
            {
              System.out.println("You recieved a C. ");
            }
    else if(grade < 90)
            {
              System.out.println("You recieved a B. ");
            }
    else if(grade < 100)
            {
              System.out.println("You recieved a A. ");
            }
        inputFile.close();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What is the issue that is happening? Simply saying "it doesn't work" isn't useful.

Comment: Sorry about that, the outcome of this code is getting to write in the name of the file and obtaining 60 random numbers from the file. Although for some reason it's not going into the if-else statement. For example, if one of the random numbers is 85 it should  say "You received a B." but it doesn't but instead stops the build after it does it 60 random numbers

Comment: You read into the "number" variable, `number = inputFile.nextInt();`, but then are checking against the "grade" variable, `if(grade < 60)`.

Comment: Also, calling Scanner.close() while IN the while loop is probably not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes in your code. I have corrected them. Note the comments in the below code. You have variables that are not required. I have indicated them in the code below. Some lines were changed and they are indicated by the comment `// change here`

You only need to create one instance of `Random` so move that line to before the `for` loop.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gradings {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String filename;
//        String aNum; <- not required

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Name of the file
        System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
        filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Opens the file
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);

        // Hopefully gets data from the method and writes it
        Random randomNumbers = new Random(); // Moved outside of 'for' loop.
        for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
            int min = 50;
            int max = 100;

            int x = randomNumbers.nextInt(max - min) + min;
            System.out.println("The grades are : " + x);
//            aNum = keyboard.nextLine(); <- not required
            outputFile.println(x); // change here
        }

        // Closes file
        outputFile.close();
        System.out.println("Grades have been written to the file.");

//        int number = 0; <- not required
        int grade = 0;

        // making sure file exists
        File file = new File(filename);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("The file " + filename + "is not found.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // opens file and reads
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) { // change here
            // Read values from file adn reads it
            grade = inputFile.nextInt(); // change here

            if (grade < 60) {
                System.out.println("You recieved an F. ");
            }
            else if (grade < 70) {
                System.out.println("You recieved a D. ");
            }
            else if (grade < 80) {
                System.out.println("You recieved a C. ");
            }
            else if (grade < 90) {
                System.out.println("You recieved a B. ");
            }
            else if (grade < 100) {
                System.out.println("You recieved a A. ");
            }
        }
        inputFile.close(); // moved to oustside the 'while' loop
    }
}
```